# git bundle: bundle tags and heads

Tags: git, bundle

I develop on several machines. I want to have a repository for each of my projects on each development machine, and I would like to keep them in sync without using a remote repository I can push to. (For now I cannot afford a dedicated machine for that purpose).

I think git bundle is the right tool for the job. I simply bundle my repo when I am done working on machine A, and unbundle on machine B. This leaves me with this questions:

Is it possible to embed information about tags and branches in the bundle? In particular, how can I bundle tag objects?

EDIT: Just a note aside - I want to keep this workflow as automated as possible. I do not want to treat the bundle as a remote. Rather than that, I would like to duplicate the bundle into my repository - that is add commits and tags, fast-forward existing branches and add new branches if the branch does not exist.

Answer (score 17):

```
git bundle create RA.bundle --branches --tags
```

would include informations about all tags and all branches.

> [`git bundle`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html) takes a list of arguments, acceptable to [`git rev-parse`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html) and [`git rev-list`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) (and containing a named ref, see [SPECIFYING REFERENCES](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html#_specifying_references)), that specifies the specific objects and references to transport.

```
--branches[=<pattern>]
```

> Pretend as if all the refs in `refs/heads` are listed on the command line as `<commit>`.
>   If `<pattern>` is given, limit branches to ones matching given shell glob.
>   If pattern lacks `?`, `,` or `[`, `/` at the end is implied.

```
--tags[=<pattern>]
```

> Pretend as if all the refs in refs/tags are listed on the command line as `<commit>`.
>   If `<pattern>` is given, limit tags to ones matching given shell glob.
>   If pattern lacks `?`, `,` or `[, /` at the end is implied.

Comment: Anyone figured out how to do this including tags that are in a commit range, as opposed to all tags like the above solution does?

Comment: @robinspb You can do like `git bundle create ^fromReference currentReference`. for commit range.