# git migration from Windows NTFS to Linux ext4

Tags: git

I have a git repo on Windows. Now I installed dual boot to linux on the same machine.

In linux, I mounted the NTFS and I did

```
cp -r /media/OS/Users/xl/git/xyz ~/git/xyz
```

then since I've worked on linux at ~/git/xyz and also have git committed (locally).

Did I just screw up my git info? If so, how to fix?

Unfortunately, there's no any remote repository nor any pristine backup, because I already rysnc's back to the NTFS one from linux. (NTFS is case-insensitve but case aware, if that matters)

thanks.

Comment: What makes you think anything is wrong? If you started the project on Windows, your repo is unlikely to contain filenames that differ only in case. The only concern I can think of is line endings in any files you changed.

Comment: was thinking maybe the .git files contained hardcoded path or something. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have broken anything, but just in case, you can check that by [making a bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5720366/6309), rather than copying the content of a repo.

A git bundle results in *one* file, that you can easily copy over, and from which you can *clone* your repo in your Linux session.
This is the surest way to avoid any file corruption during a cp or a rsynch.

But if you can see the windows path from your Linux session, even easier would be to clone directly that repo, or push back to it (rather than copying the full repo content)