# git: repack locally, push the repacked objects

Tags: git, git-gc

Is there any way for me to do the repack work on the local machine, then push the resulting packed database to my remote repository?

Comment: I'm not entirely happy with the question, as it uses terms like *packing* without actually describing the use case.

Answer (score 1):

The closest would be to use **[`git bundle`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle)**, which re-pack and store the all repo into *one* file.
I mentioned it in "[How can I email someone a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2545784/6309)". You can [include tags as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5720366/6309).

The added benefit is that one file is easier to transfer.

Once copied over the remote server, you can clone or fetch from that bundle file.