# Merge conflict on branch in github

Tags: git, github

I have 2 files `firtst-page.html` and `first-page.html` new lines  added to first-page.html file from different branches. While merging results in conflicts and can't revert.. one pull request with following lines

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>this is master file</h1>
who is this
</body>
</html>
```

another pull request with

```
<html>
<body> 
<h1>this is master file</h1> 
firtst-page firtst-page firtst-page  
</body>
</html>
```

My questions are

1. How to resolve this conflict?
2. Why such conflict?
3. Do github allow multiple pull request at a time?

Comment: This sounds like user error, not a Git problem.

Comment: I think you should search for 'how to solve conflicts in Git

Comment: You need to learn the technology you are trying to use. The questions you are asking show you lack a basic understanding of file versioning.

Comment: I saw the answer accepted for a few seconds... anything missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time a file does evolve both in the source branch and the destination branch, there can be conflicts.

More specifically, there will be conflicts on common line with different modified content.

To resolve those conflicts, you can report to "[How to resolve merge conflicts in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5720366/6309)", but you also can, more recently (Dec. 2016), resolve them directly from the GitHub web GUI.
See "[Resolve simple merge conflicts on GitHub](https://github.com/blog/2293-resolve-simple-merge-conflicts-on-github)"

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/7321362/21116820/fd64b010-c06b-11e6-9dd3-a827e299c5bf.gif]

You cannot accept multiple PR without merging them locally first, then making a new PR with the result of that merge (or updating an existing one)